# Field shows in Pentaho designer but not in OpenERP

Tags: openerp-7

I am new to Pentaho (5.01) and Open ERP(7.0) I have an existing report that I have added a field (text), that is a selection in the corresponding module.

In the Pentaho Report Designer Preview the value of the field is correct, however after loading the .prpt into OpenERP the report runs (PDF) and all the other fields are populated correctly except this one.

Is there some setting I am missing in OpenERP that is preventing display of this field? The field value is also correct in the DB (Postgres) table.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the pentaho.server.url had been hardwired to an IP address.

In our OpenERP installation we have three servers, production, demo (copy of production) and development, The pentaho.server.url stored as a record in the ir_config_parameter table in the Postgres DB on developmen, has been pointed to the Pentaho report server for production. So even though I was loading the correct .prpt report file on the development system the query was pulling data from the production system which did not have the correct DB data or structure.

I deciphered this by debugging the report activation and calling code in the core.py (community/pentaho_reports) module.